What is the precise definition of "defined over $\mathbb{Q}$" in the definition of a Hodge structure?
In Definition 1 of this note https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~looij101/trentorendicontifinal.pdf  : "a Hodge structure on V is a decomposition $\mathrm{V}=\oplus_{\mathfrak{p}, \mathrm{q}} \mathrm{V}^{\mathrm{p}, \mathrm{q}}$ with $\overline{\mathrm{V}^{\mathrm{p}, \mathrm{q}}}=\mathrm{V}^{\mathrm{q}, \mathfrak{p}}$ such that for every $\mathrm{m}, \oplus_{\mathfrak{p}+\mathrm{q}=\mathrm{m}} \mathrm{V}^{\mathrm{p}, \mathrm{q}}$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.   Its Weil element is the transformation $\mathrm{C} \in \mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{V})$ which on $\mathrm{V}^{\mathrm{p}, \mathrm{q}}$ is multiplication by $i^{\mathrm{p}-\mathrm{q}}$. .......
Notice that the Weil element is defined over $\mathbb{R}$."

Question: What is  the precise definition of the notion "defined over
$\mathbb{Q}$"?

clues: I don't know what is  the precise definition of the "defined over $\mathbb{Q}$" (the direct sum of the complex spaces $V^{p,q}$ is of course $Q$-module).  According to
the wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_structure of Hodge structure, I guess that a complex space $W$ (not necessarily finite dimensional) "is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$"  means that there is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $W_1$  such that  $W=W_1\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}$.

The idea is that from the beginning $V$ is a complex vector space defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, meaning that actually we are given a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $U$, and $V=U\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}$.
We have a decomposition $V = \bigoplus_{p,q} V^{p,q}$ as $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces. For each $m$, let us write $V_m = \bigoplus_{p+q=m}V^{p,q}$. Clearly $V=\bigoplus_m V_m$.
Then we require that there exists a decomposition $U = \bigoplus_m U_m$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces such that $V_m = U_m\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}$.
On the other hand, it is not required that there exists $U^{p,q}\subset U$ such that $V^{p,q}= U^{p,q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}$.

Thank you  for your complete answer.  Could you  recommend a  reference on this?

Not really, this is just a translation in more explicit terms of the article you provided a link to.
